# Regex ? in lookbehind not consuming

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Lookbehind with ? is not consuming the **:**

Regex:

```
(?i)(?<=\bsubject:?).+$
```

Text:

Subject:    asdf adsf

Match

**:**    asdf adsf

I don't want the **:** to be included in the match

If I search on:
Subject    asdf adsf
It matches:
asdf adsf
That is the behavior I want
It appears to treat the : as optional but not consuming

If I match on just subject:? it is greedy and includes the **:**

Comment: Your examples don't make it clear that lookahead is necessary.  Are you sure it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex `(?i)(?<=\bsubject:?)[^:].*$`

Comment: @Blam `.+` catches `:` but not lookbehind

Comment: You should include that explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a question mark after the : which will make the colon optional.

```
(?i)(?<=\bsubject:).+$
```

Comment: Exactly I want it to be optional.  I also want it to be consuming.

Answer (score 0):

This works ok for me:

`(?i)(?<=subject:).+$`

Remove the extra question mark.

Comment: But I want it to be optional.  This will not match on Subject asdf adsf.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood, I don't think you need a look-ahead for this?

If you're just after whatever follows `Subject`, then this is your regex:

`Subject\:?(.+)$`

And if you're after whatever follows `Subject`, `subject` or eg `suBject` then this is your regex:

`(?i)Subject\:?(.+)$`

And include your word-boundary `\b` again if that's still necessary:

`\bSubject\:?(.+)$` or `(?i)\bSubject\:?(.+)$`

So, in C#.NET:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?i)Subject\:?(.+)$");

Match m = r.Match("Subject asdf asdf");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);

m = r.Match("Subject: asdf asdf");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]); 

//Both output ' asdf asdf' - you might want to trim this.  
//Or add optional space \s? after the optional colon \:? in your regex.
```

Or, rather than relying on magic constants to line up with implicitly numbered capture groups, explicitly name (and reference) the group:

```
string captureName = "yourcap";

Regex r = new Regex(@"(?i)Subject\:?(?<"+captureName+">.+)$");
Match m = r.Match("Subject asdf asdf");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[captureName]);
```

Comment: But I want the : to be optional (and consuming)

Comment: @Blam so to be clear, if the `:` is present immediately after `Subject` that's fine, but you don't want it included in your match?  Answer updated to reflect that.

Comment: What part of optional is not clear?   I want it to match on Subject    asdf adsf.

Comment: @Blam It _IS_ optional in this regex. What I was asking was _if_ the `:` is present, do you want it _included in the match_? As it sits, this _WILL_ match on "Subject asdf adsf" (" asdf asdf" will be captured), and it _WILL ALSO_ match on "Subject: asdf asdf" (again, " asdf asdf" will be captured).

Comment: My comment was based on and earlier version without the ?.   You fix includes Subject: in the match.  I don't want Subject in the match.  That is the purpose of the lookbehind.

Comment: @Blam Then your comment was almost 10 minutes too late ;-).  Yes, it will _match_ "Subject", but I'm saying that if you rely on the _capture group_, then the overall _match_ becomes irrelevant (other than to indicate "yes, it matched, and the info you're interested in is in the capture").  If all you're after is "what text follows 'Subject' or 'Subject:'" then this regex will provide that for you (in the _capture_ group) without complexity/processing required for lookarounds.

Comment: @Blam I assumed you understood "capture groups" based on your knowledge of lookarounds... but just in case... a capture group allows you to, well, "capture" a section of the match that you're interested in.  This allows you to do a complete match, even though you may not be interested in the entire match (eg, exclude "Subject:" from your "result").  Capture groups are surrounded by parenthesis, and generally returned in an array of "matches" (where index 0 is generally the whole match, and then subsequent matches generally correspond to each capture group).

Comment: OK yes I know about groups but use of groups was not clear from your answer and does not fit into how I want to use this.  I am reading in the Regex pattern from SQL and need the pattern alone to return the desired result.

Comment: @Blam Your question is tagged .NET hence I understood that capture groups were available for you to use. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Blam yes, as per 1. my comment above re tagging, 2. I asked you for clarification about your requirement 14 hours ago (as per my comment below your question) and didn't receive any, 3. There is no actual question in your question, it's just a series of statements. 4. You've been generally rude and arrogant despite my genuine efforts to assist you

Comment: I have an answer and I told you I did not want to use groups.

Comment: @Blam Yes, you have an answer. Of four different regex-knowledgeable people, only one knew what you were asking. Gold, a retaliatory down-vote! The adult on your profile pic wants his photo back! :-).